# Add scroll delay to fullpage.js sections and slides

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I am trying to add a scroll delay to my fullpage.js sections and slides.

I got this working for sections only using the following code.

```
var delay = 1000;
var scrollDelay = false;

$("#sections-container").fullpage({
    navigation: true,
    controlArrows: false,
    slidesNavigation: true,
    scrollHorizontally: true,
    sectionSelector: ".main-section",
    slideSelector: ".sub-section",

    onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction) {
      timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        scrollDelay = true;
        fullpage_api.moveTo(destination.index + 1);
        scrollDelay = false;
      }, delay);
      return scrollDelay;
});
```

How would I go about adding a scrolling delay for both sections and slides?

Comment: I think this can be done with `transition-delay` property.

Comment: Use the same idea but using the `onSlideLeave` callback too.

Answer (score 0):

`fitToSectionDelay: 1000,` try this in function, It is for fullpage.js

Answer (score 0):

In the object of fullpage method you should add these options:

```
fitToSection: true,
fitToSectionDelay: 1000
```

Change 1000 with the number that you want. Is configured by milliseconds.